# javascript: dynamic call of nested function

Tags: javascript, dynamic

in an existing implementation (can't change the structure much), i'm trying to call a function which is nested inside another function:

```
function outer(innerFunction, obj) {

    //TODO: call innerFunction here, passing obj as first parameter

    function inner1(obj) {
        alert(obj.key);
    }
}
outer('inner1', {key:'value'});
```

jsfiddle is here: http://jsfiddle.net/tbyyw/

i've alreay thought about using `eval()`, but i don't know how to pass an object - and they say 'eval is evil' ;)

another solution i've come up with is checking the innerFunction string, but this means i have to know which inner functions exist (besides, adding new functions would mean having to write extra checks then):

```
if(innerFunction == 'inner1') inner1(obj);
```

so is there another way without changing the overall implementation?

Comment: This question is hard to answer. What's the original implementation and wich parts of the overall implementation can be changed? From your code snippet it doesn't look like `outer` already exists.

Comment: the implementation already exists, so does the 'outer' function (i've just changed the identifiers to simplify things)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without changing the overall structure `eval` appears to be the only option:

```
function outer(funcName, obj) {

    var func = eval(funcName);
    func(obj);

    function inner1(obj) {
        alert(obj.key);
    }
}
```

There's nothing particularly "evil" about `eval` as long as you have full control over the code, but if you want, you can insert an additional security check:

```
if (funcName.match(/\W/))
    throw "invalid function name!";

var func = eval(funcName);
```

This will raise an exception if someone tries to pass anything else than a simple identifier, i.e. a function name.

Comment: seems like the best option, thanks for showing how to pass an object using 'eval' here.

Comment: Using `eval` can severely compromise 'minifying' (compression) algorithms of your script.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you wanted?

```
function outer(innerFunction, obj) {

    var fn = {
        inner1: function (obj) {
            alert(obj.key);
        } 
    };

    fn[innerFunction](obj);
}

outer('inner1', {key:'value'});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/tbyyw/1/

Comment: this means having to rewrite the 'inner' functions, which is not what i want

Comment: You are just renaming them, not rewriting them. The bottom line is there is no enumeration of local variables. So you have 3 options: 1) use eval. 2) switch statements or an index object. 3) put the variables in question into an enumerated object. I think 3 is best as it is safest.

Comment: you're right, it's no 'rewrite', i just don't want to touch the code block containing the inner functions at all - anyway, +1 for providing a viable solution

Answer (score 0):

A simple switch statement would be least intrusive. Or is the function name completely dynamic?

```
function outer(innerFunction, obj) {

     switch (innerFunction) {
        case "inner1": inner1(obj); break;            
    }

    function inner1(obj) {
        alert(obj.key);
    }
}
outer('inner1', {key:'value'});
​
```

Comment: i've already mentioned this in my question (using a 'if' statement instead of 'switch')